# Relatively simple OTP code generated by SafeNet MobilePass

Tags: authentication, key-management, one-time-password

I noticed something peculiar while logging into the VPN of the company I work for.

I generated a one-time passcode from MobilePass, and the code displayed was “010010”. I captured an image of this occurrence, and am considering handing this over to the CISO.

Is it mathematically possible this code could be generated considering the algorithms backing a product such as MobilePass, or does it need to be reported?

Comment: Every OTP token I've ever used, mostly RSA and CryptoCard, exhibit behavior of 'hard to believe that's random' output.  I think the problem is not the tokens, but the [human affinity for creating patterns out of number strings](http://stuff.alienbill.com/tip/).  As long as the next token code wasn't 010011, I think you're okay.

Comment: Don't you know, that the mobile Pass is a digital device? This was actually 19. ;-) If you have an old Vasco Digipass GO these in fact use the first digit as a syncronizer. It moves from 0-9 from 0-9...

Comment: @gowenfawr great link! Thx for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

0.0064% (that's .2^6) of the numbers in a random 6 digit string will only have 0's and 1's. You got one. No big deal. It's only a problem if those numbers occur more than  0.0064% of the time or you can predict when they will occur.

If you pay attention, and wait long enough, you'll see that 1 in 1,000,000 of the random numbers will be your birth date in the form DDMMYY. You can reduce your expected wait time by half by also looking for your birthday in the form MMDDYY. In general, if you treat enough numbers as significant, you're bound to see them all the time.